# Disable the vertical scroll bar in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say that I have a shiny dashboard uses by default a vertical scroll bar because of a large plot  in the right side but for some reason I do not want it there even if the plot is not displayed as a whole. I do not want to reduce the plot height as well.Can this be done?

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 850)),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: whats the point in having a plot oversized and removing a scroll bar to view it or I am missing something here ?

Comment: ok check now I reduced the plot height to 850px ...i can see the whole of it but still the scroll bar is there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following css should do it : `body {overflow-y: hidden;}`

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        "body {overflow-y: hidden;}"
      )
    ),
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 850)),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```